# Java NIO, reads not completing

Tags: java, sockets, http, networking, nio

I am attempting to write a simple HTTP async server and a test client. My test client makes a bunch of requests to the server, but doesn't do anything with the response except read it. The problem I'm running into is after a bunch of successful responses, my client fails to read the full response of a particular request. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is the read/write handler for my server:
[read/write handler](http://pastebin.com/RY7JS6kk)

The important code is the function that sends the file:

```
    public void handleWrite(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    client.write(out); // Write the headers to the stream
    if (state == State.SENDING_RESPONSE && out.remaining() == 0) {
        // We are done writing the headers
        if (sendFile && (mapped == null)) {
            // Send the file via direct transfer
            System.err.println("DT: " + fPath + " " + pos + "/" + fileSize);
            long transferred = f.transferTo(pos, fileSize, client);
            pos += transferred;
            System.err.println("DT: " + fPath + " " + pos + "/" + fileSize);
        } else if (mapped != null){
            // Send the file (in mapped from either filesystem or from
            // cache)
            System.err.println("MAPPED: " + fPath + " " + mapped.position() + "/" + mapped.limit());
            written += client.write(mapped);
            System.err.println("MAPPED: " + fPath + " " + written + "/" + mapped.limit());
        }
    }
    if (out.remaining() == 0
            && ((mapped == null && pos == fileSize) || (mapped != null && mapped
                    .remaining() == 0))) {
        // We are done transferring the file!
        System.err.println(pos + " " + fileSize);
        assert (pos == fileSize) || (mapped.position() == mapped.limit()) : "File not sent.";
        // Must reset position if from cache
        if (inCache) {
            mapped.position(0);
        }
        if (sendFile) {
            cache();
            f.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
        state = State.SOCKET_CLOSED;
        d.getKey(client).cancel();
        client.close();
    }
}
```

and here is the response handler in the client:
[response handler](http://pastebin.com/ZCQx0aPw)

Important code is the read part:

```
        if((sz = header.get("content-length")) != null) {
        bodySize = Integer.parseInt(sz);
        byte[] buff = new byte[bodySize];
        int k = 0, read = 0;
        while((k = connection.getInputStream().read(buff, read, bodySize - read)) != -1 && read < bodySize) {
            read += k;
        }
        assert read == bodySize : "Not all of file read. " + read + " " + bodySize;
    }
```

The assertion at the bottom of the response handler is the one that's failing. I've also included the server and dispatcher themselves, as well as the client if thats helpful.
[server/dispatcher](http://pastebin.com/cp53Tigk)
[client](http://pastebin.com/7t6WX6LG)

Comment: Rather than giving links to the source code, paste valid snippets here.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would not hurt.

Comment: will get on it, it's difficult to isolate this problem from the rest of the server though

Answer (score 0):

```
while((k = connection.getInputStream().read(buff, read, bodySize - read)) != -1 && read < bodySize) {
      read += k;
```

Throw that away and use `DataInputStream.readFully(data).`